# Problem with selectSingleNode on ms-access vba

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access, domdocument, msxml2

I use this simple sub on access vba

```
Public Sub ReadXml()
    ' XML FILE:
    ' <A>
    '     <B>sometext</B>
    ' </A>
    Dim n As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim n1 As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Const NomeFile = "C:\file.xml"
    n.async = False
    n.validateOnParse = False
    If n.Load(NomeFile) Then
        Set n1 = n.selectSingleNode("A/B")
        Debug.Print n1.Text ' <===  error
    End If
End Sub
```

When run i recive a 91 runtime error

Answer (score 0):

XPath in `selectSingleNode()`should be “A/B” (forward slash, not the backslash you used)